# Python Matrix, rows and columns

Tags: python, matrix

I have some problem matrix:

```
b=   [[-2.5,  0.5],        #b is random matrix
     [-1.5, -0.5],
     [-0.5,  0.5]]
```

How can from b get:

```
b=[[[-2.5], [0.5]], [[-1.5], [-0.5]], [[-0.5], [0.5]]]
```

Many thanks

Comment: Is b really a matrix, or a list of lists?

Comment: it depends on b being a list or an array / matrix from numpy.

Comment: Only **class numpy.matrix**   (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) creates real matrix. Your object isn't a matrix, but a list of lists

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> b=   [[-2.5,  0.5],        #b is random matrix
     [-1.5, -0.5],
     [-0.5,  0.5]]
>>> [[[val] for val in row] for row in b]
[[[-2.5], [0.5]], [[-1.5], [-0.5]], [[-0.5], [0.5]]]
```

---

Explanation: Consider a list:

```
>>> oned = [1, 2, 3]
```

You can re-create it with a list comprehension:

```
>>> [val for val in oned] 
[1, 2, 3]
```

Then just wrap each element in its own list:

```
>>> [[val] for val in oned]
[[1], [2], [3]]
```

Extend that to two dimensions.

Comment: Precisely what I was going to suggest. +1

Answer (score 1):

[Claudiu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955528/python-matrix-rows-and-columns/5955569#5955569) is probably more straightforward, but here is an alternative solution which recursively walks through a list of lists of any depth.

```
>>> listify = lambda x: map(listify, x) if isinstance(x, list) else [x]
>>> listify(b)
[[[-2.5], [0.5]], [[-1.5], [-0.5]], [[-0.5], [0.5]]]
```